# Addressing a person with "man"

Tags: formality, conversation

Is there any issue to address or call a person (a gentleman, of course) with *man*? I think the word *man* has a strange meaning. Which is the best way to address? Is *hello* enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Man" is used in informal contexts. If you are talking to a friend or a new acquaintance you could address them as "man," but it is not fitting for a formal/professional environment.

Answer (score 0):

To address a "man" formally, one would say, "sir."

But "man" is okay for informal speech.